# How can I check if a UTF-8 text file has a BOM?

Tags: unicode

How can I check if a UTF-8 text file has a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) from command line?

`file` command shows me:

> ```
> UTF-8 Unicode text
> ```

But, I don't know if it means there is no BOM in the file.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Note that there is no BOM in UTF-8: that's a feature of UTF-16. An UTF-8 file may start with the U+FEFF character, but in that case it's a zero-width space.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`file` will tell you if there is a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). You can simply test it with:

```sh
printf '\ufeff...\n' | file -
/dev/stdin: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text
```

Some shells such as `ash` or `dash` have a `printf` builtin that does not support `\u`, in which case you need to use `printf` from the GNU coreutils, e.g. `/usr/bin/printf`.

---

Note: according to the `file` changelog, this feature existed already in 2007. So, this should work on any current machine.

Comment: Thanks for answer. My `file` version is `file-5.09` and the result was `/dev/stdin: ASCII text`. Is it depends on version of `file`?

Comment: Thank you for that addition! I am using POSIX `printf` and completely missed that, sorry. Cheers.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak POSIX does not specify the `\u` escape sequence (at least, not yet). It specifies `\ddd` with a 3-digit octal number, so that a portable version could be: `printf '\357\273\277...\n' | file -` (but it is rather difficult to remember).

Answer (score 9):

If you execute `stat fileName` it should give you exact the three characters. When I opened the file in the editor, I was unable to see anything. So noticing that the file size was 3 gave me clarity that it has a BOM.

Also, the post [here](https://blog.ijun.org/2011/01/to-check-if-file-contains-utf-8-bom-at.html) was helful in my case.

```
hexdump -n 3 -C 2.txt
00000000 ef bb bf
ef bb bf // YES
```

Answer (score 3):

Another variant -- `dos2unix`:

```
$ dos2unix -ib   *.txt
  no-bom f1.txt                 # this file has no BOM
  utf-8  f2.txt                 # this file has BOM + UTF-8
```

This command has options to change the file format, such as add or remove BOMs

Answer (score 1):

Using `file`, as [indicated in vinc17's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170776), did not work on my machine<sup>1</sup>. Based on [a previous answer by akshita007](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33978009) and also identified as a [solution to a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/469891), I recommend checking the first three bytes of your file

```
head -c3 [file] | hexdump -C
```

If you have a file with a BOM, the output should look something like this

```
head -c3 file-with-bom | hexdump -C
00000000  ef bb bf                                          |...|
00000003
```

Without a bom, you won't see the `EF BB BF` bytes but the actual content of the file:

```
head -c3 file-without-bom | hexdump -C
00000000  22 49 64                                          |"Id|
00000003
```

*Note: My test file has CSV content and starts with a quoted header, so it shows `"Id` as the first three bytes without a BOM.*

---

<sup>1</sup> Using file-5.41 in Ubuntu 22.04.3, I simply get *CSV text* for a  file regardless of the BOM.

Answer (score 0):

A UTF-8 file with a BOM starts with the 3 bytes 0xef 0xbb 0xbf, the UTF-8 encoding of the U+FEFF character.

You can find those files efficiently in bash by reading the first 3 bytes of the files:

```
find . -type f -size +2c -print0 |
  while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
    IFS= LC_ALL=C read -rd '' -n3 first3 < "$file" &&
      [[ $first3 = $'\xef\xbb\xbf' ]] &&
      printf '%s\n' "$file"
  done
```

That doesn't check whether the rest of the file is valid UTF-8, but then neither does `file`, it's just a heuristic.